# How to check if client was kicked?

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I need to know when my client/bot was kicked from a server. I have looked at Grepper discord.js guide and countless more but I couldn't find anything.

I'm really sure that there is a client.on event for this. Like:

```
client.on('kicked', (guild) => {
    console.log(`${client.user.username} was kicked from ${guild.name}`);
});
```

How can I check when the bot was kicked from a server and just console.log it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`guildDelete`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-guildDelete) event which is emitted whenever the client is kicked from the guild or the guild is deleted.

---

```js
client.on('guildDelete', guild => {
    console.log(`${client.user.username} was kicked from ${guild.name}.`);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

from [this cheatsheet](https://gist.github.com/koad/316b265a91d933fd1b62dddfcc3ff584)

```js
client.on("guildMemberRemove", function(member){
  console.log(`a member leaves a guild, or is kicked: ${member.tag}`);
});
```

Comment: Sorry that didnt help me. But thanks for the cheat sheat

Comment: This solution is not what the OP was asking.

Comment: This is not the answer to the question, this would log when a member is removed from the guild, not the bot.

Comment: I agree with @JoeMoore